# Причина ограничения использования формы оператора "System.out.print(ln)"?

Tags: java, print, операторы

Почему компилятор позволяет использовать в коде:

```
System.out.println("");
System.out.print("");
System.out.println();,
```

Но не позволяет использовать:

`System.out.print();` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
System.out.println("");
System.out.println();
```

Эти два оператора можно использовать в качестве перевода каретки.

```
System.out.print("");
```

Этот оператор можно использовать, поскольку один из вариантов переменной на вход - String, согласитесь, глупо было бы делать проверку на string.equals(""). Тем не менее, действительно, этот оператор в таком виде ничего не делает.

А в этом методе

```
System.out.print();
```

Просто нет смысла- он ничего не делает, поэтому его и не стали создавать

Answer (score 4):

Метода с такой сигнатурой нет в [PrintStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html). `System.out.println();` переносит на новую строку, `System.out.print();` являлся бы просто пустым оператором. Вы уверены, что он необходим?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, вопрос заключается в том, почему можно `System.out.print("")`, а `System.out.print()` нельзя

Comment: Тогда ответ в первом предложении. Есть сигнатуры `print` для примитивов, массива char, String и Object. Без аргументов нет.